# preview frame processing while recording with SDK

Tags: android

I am working on an app that should constantly process each preview frames(by passing it to a native code, which returns few boolean values as metadata). So far, everything is great. By toggling some buttons in the activity screen with respect to native code's output, I can get a live feedback of what's happening.

However, can I record these frames as a video while processing each frame, using MediaRecorder? Android SDK version I use is 2.2. Thanks a lot.